# Confused about Cognito app clients and custom scopes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Please correct me if otherwise. OAuth scopes defines an application's access to a user's account while custom scopes define an application's access to a resource server. After signing in, an access token is returned containing the custom scopes, which depend on the query string parameters in the Cognito domain.

Is the purpose of an app client's custom scopes to define its permission to protected resources just to ensure users are logged in from a specified app?

A User Pool can have multiple app clients, each with their own custom scopes. Why not grant all app clients access to all custom scopes? Most apps allow anyone to signup, couldn't users just login in through an app client that has a different set of custom scopes anyway? Is it a least privilege thing? Is it meant for apps that have a restricted sign up, such as paid membership? And if using a web client, the client id is exposed and there's no secret, so how does a client id prevent others from obtaining the id and posing as an app client?

How does this tie in with user specific permissions? Seems like custom scopes are only for resources that are app specific, but not user specific. Do you implement custom logic for authorizing access to specific resources, or can this also be also done with User Pools?

Also, please recommend any resources besides AWS documentation (which I've read) regarding Cognito that really help explain the use cases and entire process.